# Time taken to experience a force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Suppose I have a body of mass $M$ kept on a horizontal smooth surface. I strike that particle with some force ,providing an impulse $\overrightarrow{J_1}$. The applied force is in vertically downward direction. Suppose that the body deforms in this process and it doesn't rebound. What I want to know is, whether the impulsive normal starts to act as soon as I apply a force or is there a time lag between the two? In other words I can look at this situation from two angles:-

1. Either I view it as a series of impulses imparted to the body. Which means that the particle when struck by external means, gains some velocity and then it's again acted upon by an impulsive normal which brings it to halt.
2. Or impulsive normal starts to act as soon as the external impulse is acting. That is the body doesn't gain any velocity at any instant.

Which approach should I consider?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a time lag between your applied force starting to act and an extra normal force (from the surface the body is resting on) starting to act roughly equal to

$$\frac{\text{thickness of body (top to bottom) }}{\text{speed of sound in body}}.$$ 
For most purposes this time lag is negligible. But if you're concerned with these very short-lived effects, the wave set up by your applied force will partly reflect from the body's lower surface, travel upwards and partly reflect from the top surface and so on. It will be dissipated in a very short time, after which the forces on the body will be as you would usually think them to be.

Comment: Can I use the same concept in case of consecutive collisions? Take for example two solid spheres in contact with each other placed on a smooth horizontal surface and a third sphere collides head on with this system. And should I apply coefficient of restitution equation step by step or taking initial and final conditions?

Comment: The same concept will no doubt apply to multiple collisions, but I believe that the coefficient of restitution doesn't take these short-term effects into account, but deals only with the initial and final velocities of the bodies' centres of mass.

Comment: My purpose for asking this question is to build upon a perspective to look at these situations. I thought the coefficient of restitution equation is applied only for one collision. Let's say that in the aforementioned example , the spheres in contact are going to collide inelastically while the approaching sphere collides elastically with the second one. I would break this into series of two consecutive collisions rather than multiple collisions acting at the same instant.

Comment: Let's assume all the spheres have the same mass equal to m. I view the collision as an elastic one between the 1st and the 2nd. During this process the 1st sphere comes to rest and the 2nd one gains a velocity equal to that of the initial velocity of the 1st sphere. But as soon as it gains velocity (here I assume a complete transfer of momentum without external impulse by the third sphere due to time lag) the impulse starts to act between 2nd and 3rd.After the series of collisions the first one comes to halt and the rest of the system moves with v/2. Am I viewing it  correctly ?

Comment: You seem to me to have a very good understanding of what's going on. I now see why you're interested in time lags. What I'm not happy about – maybe someone who knows more than me will come to the rescue – is whether the impulse that travels through the sphere as a wave is representative of the motion of the sphere as a whole. In elementary treatments of a sequence of collisions (e.g. in a 'Newton's cradle' set-up) we usually avoid the difficulty by assuming that there are small gaps between the spheres, so that each sphere is moving as a whole, before it collides with the next.

Comment: That was the answer I was expecting. Thank you very much sir for throwing light on this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it clear what model you are using. First you talk about striking a *particle* which is a point mass with no structure. Then it becomes a *body* which implies that it occupies space. Then it *deforms*, so it is not a rigid body. In your comments to Philip Wood you talk about *multiple collisions* within the body, which is now made up of solid parts which interact instantanously on contact.

In all cases, the impulse which you apply obeys Newton's 3rd Law. You cannot apply a force on a target without the target applying the same force back on the hammer. This is true at all times, without any delay.

When the hammer makes contact with the target, the force between them increases gradually as the target and hammer deform. If the target and hammer are elastic and obey Hooke's Law then the force between them is maximum when the deformation is maximum. However, you specify that the target does not rebound. Presumably it is permanently deformed, and does not obey Hooke's Law. The final force is the weight of the hammer. It is not possible to say how the force varies in between start and finish positions in this case.